# Linq using nullable datetime field

Tags: linq

I have a problem with LINQ (using EF - 4.3.1.0) using the following:

```
    DateTime? dtcollected = DateTime.TryParse(dateCollected, out dateVal) ? dateVal : (DateTime?)null;
    DateTime?  dtanalyzed =  DateTime.TryParse(dateanalyzed, out dateVal) ? dateVal : (DateTime?)null; 


     var doesexist = (from pw in dbContext.WtTbl                                      
                      where pw.CompanyId == 13
                      && pw.DateCollected == dtcollected
                      && pw.DateAnalyzed == dtanalyzed                                    
                      select pw).Any();
```

Note that dateCollected came in as a string so I had to convert it to a nullable DateTime. Same goes for dateanalyzed.

What I am struck at is that I have a companyId of 13. A null value of dtcollected. And a value for dtanalyzed already in the table so I would expect doesexist to return true, but it returns false.

If I comment out

```
     var doesexist = (from pw in dbContext.WtTbl                                      
                      where pw.CompanyId == 13
                    //   && pw.DateCollected == dtcollected
                      && pw.DateAnalyzed == dtanalyzed                                    
                      select pw).Any();
```

or put:

```
      var doesexist = (from pw in dbContext.WtTbl                                      
                      where pw.CompanyId == 13
                      && pw.DateCollected == null
                      && pw.DateAnalyzed == dtanalyzed                                    
                      select pw).Any();
```

Then I get a true. How come it is not able to comprehend null value of dtcollected?
Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: LINQ to what? This looks like an EF bug that was fixed in 4.5

Comment: Yes, pwDateCollected is null in table and dtcollected is null in c# for that specific record.

Comment: Yep, EF cannot handle a query with where <column> == <objectvalue> where both are NULL. This should be translated to <column> IS NULL but it translates to <column> = NULL which does not give the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most database systems (definitely SQL Server), if one side of the comparison is null, then the result of the comparison is unknown, and therefore not included in the result set (or, for all intents and purposes, false).

That said, you need to perform a check for null against your variables, only checking against the database field if the parameter is non-null, like so:

```
var doesexist = (
    from pw in dbContext.WtTbl                                      
    where 
        pw.CompanyId == 13 && 
        (dtcollected == null || pw.DateCollected == dtcollected) &&
        (dtanalyzed == null || pw.DateAnalyzed == dtanalyzed)
    select pw).Any();
```

This translates roughly to:

```
declare @dtcollected date = null
declare @dtanalyzed date = null

select 
    * 
from 
    Table as t
where
    (@dtcollected is null or t.DateCollected = @dtcollected) and
    (@dtanalyzed is null or t.DateAnalyzed  = @dtanalyzed)
```